# What does 我是足不出户的半宅体 mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

Can somebody help me translate this sentence?

> 我是足不出户的半宅体

Using a dictionary, I guess it describes a person who doesn't want to leave his house. But I am not sure what is the exact meaning of it.

Comment: 足不出户 （成语）lit. not putting a 足foot outside
不出户to stay at home
never step out of doors; confine oneself within doors
 remain within doors; remain quietly at home behind closed doors; keep (stay) indoors; be confined to the house; never to go out; never to leave one's home
半宅体 (for meaning of individual characters see dictionary) seems to have been borrowed from Japanese (denoting a type of individual), see Japanese dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up 宅男，宅女， that will point you in the right direction.

我是足不出户的半宅体?
I'm a never-goes-out kind of half a nerd.

Comment: 半宅体 implies that he still go out a bit more often than those 宅男，宅女s. This sentence is hard to translate.

Comment: How about, "I am a house-bound sissy"